# Sub Query possibility instead of using JOIN?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to write the code below using a sub query and not use JOIN statement?

```
SELECT Nurse_no, Nurse.Name, Auxilary_No, Patient.Name
FROM Nurse LEFT OUTER JOIN Patient
ON Nurse_no = Agency_Nurse_No;
```

Any help is grately appreciated.

Ben

Comment: from a performance point of view sub queries are very slow compared to joins so i would stick to joins rather than sub queries

Comment: FYI outers are slower than inners and in your example would make no difference to functionality

Comment: The real question is: why would you want to specifically use a subquery? Doesn't that query achieve the desired result? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
select
   nurse_no,
   nurse.name,
   auxiliary_no,
   (select name from patient where agency_nurse_no = nurse_no) as PatientName
from
    nurse
```

However, MySQL doesn't optimize subqueries very well, and the join is probably much faster. Benchmarking will tell you which one wins, but that's my guess.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but the JOIN will probably be faster.

```
SELECT Nurse_no, Nurse.Name, Auxilary_No, (select Name from Patient where agency_nurse_no = Nurse.Nurse_no) as PatientName
FROM Nurse;
```

I'm no SQL expert, but I would expect the JOIN operation to execute much faster than the subquery which probably will execute per row.

Comment: What happens if there are multiple patients per Nurse?